# Lightning Experience swallowing errors?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

Before, whenever there was a Javascript runtime error in an Aura Component, a 'Something went wrong' modal would pop up and I would get a stack trace for the error. This only happened inside Lightning experience and not in Lightning Communities. The communities would annoyingly swallow the error and give no feedback.

Now i'm working in this new sandbox that swallows errors both in Communities and inside Lightning. So in order to see where something breaks I need to do something like this.

```
try {
    // code where I suspect something is wrong
}
catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

And it is quite annoying. I already tried enabling debug mode for lightning components but it still swallows any runtime errors. Is this a change I missed for the Summer 19 release or am I missing a configuration in this sandbox?

Thank you!

EDIT:

It could be any code that throws a runtime error for example:

```
var a = 23;
a(); // Error: a is not a function
```

Before I would get this screen. https://d2r1vs3d9006ap.cloudfront.net/s3_images/1725531/RackMultipart20180418-21972-4aaw5m-2018-04-18_15-04-28_inline.png?1524078477

But now nothing happens, the error just gets swallowed by salesforce.

Comment: Maybe you can check the response errors in the Network tab.

Comment: can you add relevant code snippets?

Comment: I edited the main post with more info